# how to requestfocus on startactivity

Tags: android

so when my `scanactivity` starts up  my `cardnumberbox` requesting focus 
and from here i scan in some barcodes that will be pasted into `cardnumberbox` and then
my `shelfnumberbox` requestfocus and then i start up my camactivity  where I just take some pictures and after that i go back to my scanactivity but it is my `cardnumberbox` gets focused again instead of `shelfnumberbox`

so how do i getting my shelfnumberbox to get the focus when i start up my scanactivity from my camactivity

```
//Scan activity
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cardnumberbox.requestFocus();}
        String k = getIntent().getStringExtra("cardid");
        cardnumberbox.setText(k);
}
 cardnumberbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                String text1 = cardnumberbox.getText().toString().trim();
                if (text1.equals("R")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.Skan_Udfyld_Kort_Nummer), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    cardnumberbox.setText("");
                    cardnumberbox.requestFocus();
                } else if (cardnumberbox.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    shelfnumberbox.requestFocus();
                }
                {
                }
            }

//cam activity
    public void btn_aprove2(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
        String carde = cardnumberbox2.getText().toString().trim();
        i.putExtra("cardid", carde);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: You need to save the focus state and restore it.

Comment: so i need some sort of `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`?

Comment: That might work. Depends on if the activity is restored or a new instance is  created.